# c++ small chance for runtime error while using std::multimap

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

Sometimes i get runtime error while using `multimap` `std::async`. Visual2019 in debug mode show this error:

> Expression: cannot dereference end map/set iterator.

Example of code that generates error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <Windows.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {

        mp.emplace(mapsize, 'f');
        mapsize += 1;
        ft = std::async([this]() {
            mx.lock();
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mapsize; i++) {
                    auto pr = mp.equal_range(i);
                    for (auto j = pr.first; j != pr.second; j++)
                        std::cout << j->second << "\n";}}
            mx.unlock(); });
    }
private:
    std::mutex mx;
    static int mapsize;
    std::future <void>ft;
    static std::multimap <int, char> mp;
};
int MyClass::mapsize;
std::multimap <int, char> MyClass::mp;


int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        new MyClass();
}
```

Edit: i have made some synchronization, but it still generates the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::async` by default runs in a separate thread. So you're accessing the same object (`mp`) from multiple threads without synchronization. This is known as a *race condition*, a form of [undefined behavior](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Unsynchronized parallel access to the same object is possible only in case of (1) multiple readers, 0 writers, or (2) 0 readers, 1 writer. In all other cases access should be serialized, for example by using a `mutex`.

But note that when using a mutex, *all* access to the shared object must be protected by the *same* mutex. So the mutex should be made `static` and be used around `mp.emplace` and `mapsize += 1`, too.

Also, for better exception safety, use `unique_lock` or `lock_guard` (RAII) instead of locking the mutex manually:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        mp.emplace(mapsize, 'f');
        mapsize += 1;
        ft = std::async([this]() {
            while (true) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                for (int i = 0; i < mapsize; i++) {
                    auto pr = mp.equal_range(i);
                    for (auto j = pr.first; j != pr.second; j++)
                        std::cout << j->second << "\n";
                }
            }
        });
    }
private:
    std::future <void>ft;
    static std::mutex mtx; // protects everything from here on down
    static int mapsize;
    static std::multimap <int, char> mp;
};
int MyClass::mapsize;
std::mutex MyClass::mtx;
std::multimap <int, char> MyClass::mp;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        new MyClass();
}
```

Comment: i`ve tried to make some synchronization, as in my edit, but it still generates the same error

Comment: @Алексей You forgot to declare the mutex as `static` too. Only one mutex for only one multimap ;)

Comment: @Алексей Not only mutex should be `static` like the object you want to protect, but you also need to change the scope of protection. Now, you only protect it from simultaneous reading, which means that map can still change while you are reading. I'm not sure if there can be any parallelization at all (unless you are okay with e.g. printing certain states twice while missing others)

Comment: I updated the answer to match the edited question. For the next time - it's better to ask a new question instead, to get more focused answers.